# How to combine web.py and dbus mainloops in one Python 3 application?

Tags: python, cherrypy, dbus, web.py, mainloop

I have a web.py based web application, which works fine. The setup boils down to:

```
app = web.application(urls_tuple, globals())
app.run()
```

Now my application also has to be D-Bus aware, i.e. it has to react to signals, which probably needs `dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop` when using `dbus-python` or `GLib.MainLoop()` when using `pydbus`. Can I combine both in one main loop or do I have to use threads and run each mainloop in one thread? If the former is possible, how? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define "combine". What are you trying to achieve here? Can you just have two separate apps/processes importing some shared event/request processing code? Are you sure you're structuring your app correctly?